# Android В Service множественные запросы к серверу

Tags: android, android-service, retrofit2, android-asynctask

У меня есть отдельный `Service` для передачи данных на сервер.
Для передачи использую `retrofit2`.

Передача происходит следующим образом:

- Сначала запрос 1 - передаем пакет текстовых данных
- В цикле Н-ое количество запросов 2, которые передают файлы
- По завершению передачи последнего файла, нужно завершить работу в `Service`

Service внутри реализует `AsyncTask`. Объект Retrofit2 формирует асинхронные запросы, которые обрабатываются callback-ами.

Не получится ли так, что в `doInBackground` после запуска первого запроса сервис завершит работу, т.к. ответа в этом методе он не будет ждать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На текущий момент решил следующим способом:
Сделал в doInBackground бесконечный цикл, с задержкой времени:

```
currentStatus = STATUS_START;
while (true) {
   //Переключение - проверяем на выход из цикла
 if (switchData())
   break;
 else
   try {
     Thread.sleep(2000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
...
private boolean switchData(){
    switch(currentStatus){
        case STATUS_LISTEN:
            //Если статус слушаем - значит ждем ответа от какого-то запроса!!!
            return false;
        case STATUS_FINISH:
            //Завершение работы
            //сообщаем обратно
             ...
            return true;
        case STATUS_START:
            //Cтатус - посылка данных
            // Сразу ставим статус - ожидание ответа 
            currentStatus = STATUS_LISTEN;
            idCurrentRequest = leelaService.uploadData(startListener, tabNum, jsonData, files.size());
            return false;
        case STATUS_SEND_FILE:
            //Статус - послать файл
            currentStatus = STATUS_LISTEN;
            File file = new File(destDir, files.get(currFile).getUrl());
            idCurrentRequest = leelaService.uploadFile(fileListener, tabNum, packageId, file);
            return false;
 ...
```